# Symfony Parent Child category relation

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Product Category table, where I have stored categories if parent_id is null then assume this is parent category if not null then it has child categories. Now the issue is I can't show parent category name in listing page, so can someone have an idea how to make a relation in Product Category entity?

`Symfony version: 3.3`

Table Structure:(product_category)

```
  id
  parent_id
  slug
  title
```

[image]

I have tried this code in ProductCategory entity but it doesn't show any relational data:

```
class ProductCategory
{
    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductCategory", mappedBy="parent")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
    */
    private $parent;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use children and parent and this is how I use It:

```
    /**
     * One ProductCategory has Many ProductCategories.
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductCategory", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $children;

    /**
     * Many ProductCategories have One ProductCategory.
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProductCategory", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $parent;
```

**EDIT**

```
   /**
     * ProductCategory constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

Getters / Setters and this stuff:

```
   /**
    * @param ProductCategory $children
    * @return $this
    */
   public function addChildren (ProductCategory $children)
   {
       $this->children[] = $children;

       return $this;
   }
```

Comment: And how I can display them in listing page?

Comment: What Alessandro explaind is called self-reference. If you extract an ArrayCollection than you just call $currentItem->getParent()->getTitle();

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad as BDS wrote is correct you just call $currentItem->getParent()->getTitle();

Comment: @BDS can you please explain ArrayCollection as a new answer?

Comment: How can I get the parent category name in Symfony template file?

Answer (score 1):

Using entity with self reference, as Alessandro described, then let's say you have all your records extracted with doctrine using $qb->(bla bla bla)->getResult(); into a variable called $categories. Then you just have to iterate through it like that:

```
foreach($categories as $category) {
   echo $category->getTitle() . ' has parent ' . ($category->getParent() ? $category->getParent()->getTitle() : 'none'); 
}
```

To understand more about array collection, read: http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html